# angular2 generate list of buttons with click binding to components

Tags: angular

I have a component which generates a list of buttons, and I'd like to bind the click event to display a child component. I have it working for a single button/component, but it uses a local variable which has the same value for each button, so doesn't work correctly:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of keys">
  <button (click)="child.toggleCollapse()">
    Display
  </button>
  <app-child-component #child [key]="key"></app-child-component>
</div>
```

So my problem is that 'child' is the same value for each button/child, and always opens the last child. My idea is to somehow bind 'key' into the '#child' ID.

What's the correct way to do this in angular2?

Comment: Is your list of buttons generated dynamically? Do you have only one `<app-child-component>` or there's one for each button?

Comment: Yes, the list is dynamic, and there's one `<app-child-component>` for each button.

Comment: Is there an `*ngFor ` involved somewhere? Could you please provide a more extensive sample of your current code?

Comment: Yes, the whole fragment is in a loop, identified by the 'key' variable. I improved the question a little.

Comment: Ok, I'm writing an answer now, hold on ;).

Comment: Sound like 'this' is not what you think maybe. clickhander =( () => {this. //enable this}).bind(this);  maybe that helps .. with addEventListener('click',this.clickhandler)) and removeEventListener('click',this.clickhandler)) in onDestroy

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. There are references to 'this' in my child, in the 'toggleCollapse' method. Do you mean that one?

Comment: If you wire up handler function on Listener, this inside clickHandler will not be what you expect.. hence the odd syntax - not clickHandler() {}

Comment: Thoroughly confused now, what listener? What clickHandler? I have a toggleCollapse method, that is all.

Comment: Ok this is weird, I created a [little plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Om2f0YuPsvM0jLMKpzuD?p=preview) resembling your current implementation and it kinda works as expected.
Are you trying to work on a collapsible/accordion kind of thing?

Comment: OK, I think I figured out what the problem was - somehow, my 'key' object was being modified elsewhere. Thanks for the plunker.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I use a solution similar to the following solution:

In parent component you can hold currently expanded child ID (-1 if no child expanded). You can pass unique child ID and currently expanded child ID to each child using @Input (passing data from parent to child). So each child knows its ID and also knows if it is currently expanded or not (index === expandedIndex). If you want to expand/collapse child (e.g. after child's button click) you can send event using @Output and EventEmitter (passing data from child to parent) to parent to change currently expanded child ID.

**Parent component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let key of keys; let index = index">
    <app-child [key]="key" [index]="index" [expandedIndex]="expandedIndex" (changeIndex)="onChangeIndex($event)"></app-child>
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  keys: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  expandedIndex: number = -1;

  onChangeIndex(index: number) {
    if (this.expandedIndex === index) {
      this.expandedIndex = -1;
    } else {
      this.expandedIndex = index;
    }
  }

}
```

**Child component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
  <div style="margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid #ddd">
    <button (click)="onExpand()">{{expandedIndex !== index ? 'Expand' : 'Collapse'}}</button>
    <div *ngIf="expandedIndex === index">
      <p>{{key}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() key: string;
  @Input() index: number;
  @Input() expandedIndex: number;
  @Output() changeIndex = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onExpand() {
    this.changeIndex.emit(this.index);
  }

}
```